# Baxter Installation error (boost vs. QT conflict)?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, baxter, boost, qt4

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I get an error while trying to build the baxter simulator by following their installation instructions on ros kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The error is specifically when I try to make the baxter_sim_io package as shown below. Any help with this regard is appreciated:

usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hp:50: Parse error at "BOOST_JOIN"
baxter_simulator/baxter_sim_io/CMakeFiles/baxter_sim_io.dir/build.make:96: recipe for target 'baxter_simulator/baxter_sim_io/include/baxter_sim_io/moc_qnode.cxx' failed
make[2]: *** [baxter_simulator/baxter_sim_io/include/baxter_sim_io/moc_qnode.cxx] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hp:50: Parse error at "BOOST_JOIN"
baxter_simulator/baxter_sim_io/CMakeFiles/baxter_sim_io.dir/build.make:91: recipe for target 'baxter_simulator/baxter_sim_io/include/baxter_sim_io/moc_baxter_io.cxx' failed
make[2]: *** [baxter_simulator/baxter_sim_io/include/baxter_sim_io/moc_baxter_io.cxx] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3111: recipe for target 'baxter_simulator/baxter_sim_io/CMakeFiles/baxter_sim_io.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [baxter_simulator/baxter_sim_io/CMakeFiles/baxter_sim_io.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j3 -l3" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260560/baxter-installation-error-(boost-vs.-qt-conflict)?/) by [majedz](https://answers.ros.org/users/30193/majedz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-04-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spooner-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/29765/spooner-dev/) on 2017-04-28**:
Check this question for suggestions [@stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455178/qt4-cgal-parse-error-at-boost-join)

**Comment by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) on 2017-04-28**:
The kinetic-devel branch is not the default branch. Make sure you've checked out kinetic-devel in both baxter_common and baxter_simulator, and then do a clean build by removing the build/ and devel/ directories.

**Comment by [majedz](https://answers.ros.org/users/30193/majedz/) on 2017-04-29**:
Used the solution suggested by @imcmahon and it worked. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For future visitors from the Internet:

Please try the [**ROS Kinetic** tab of the Baster Simulator Installation guide](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Simulator_Installation) to get up and running with Baxter Gazebo in Kinetic. Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2017-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1